# SQL query to find table which contain specific data

Tags: sql-server-2005

In am testing a application which is created using asp.net and sql server 2005.
In a form I enter a value as 'hungry minds' for a publisher field. but when i dont know in which table it is stored. Is there any query to find the table which contain the data 'Hungry minds'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create PROC [dbo].[SearchAllTables]
(
    @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN


--exec SearchAllTables 'sdsd'


    CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
    SET  @TableName = ''
    SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

    WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = ''
        SET @TableName = 
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > 
@TableName
                AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                        OBJECT_ID(
                            QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME
(TABLE_NAME)
                             ), 'IsMSShipped'
                               ) = 0
        )

        WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @ColumnName =
            (
                SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                    AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                    AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar','ntext')
                    AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
            )

            IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #Results
                EXEC
                (
                    'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(Cast(' + 
@ColumnName + ' AS NVARCHAR(Max)), 3630) 
                    FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE Cast(' + @ColumnName + ' AS NVARCHAR(Max)) LIKE ' + 
@SearchStr2
                )
            END
        END 
    END

    SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
END
```

Answer (score 1):

No, not without some trickery. You're generally expected to know the details of your schema.

What you *can* do is to write a script of some sort to query system tables to construct queries for finding it.

By that I mean most DBMS' have system tables which contain database metadata like table names and column names. For example, DB2/z has `SYSIBM.SYSTABLES` and `SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS`.

I'm not sure what the SQLServer equivalents are off the top of my head since, as mentioned, I generally know the details of my schema :-)

You can use these tables to construct queries for querying the "real" tables.